# How to get Amazon S3 file content after reading the object

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I'm reading objects from Amazon S3 using the GetObject method from AWS SDK go v2

```
    input := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(w.Bucket),
    Key:    key,
}
object, _ := w.Client.GetObject(ctx, input)
return object
```

I have access to the object's content size, and to the file type, and there is a parameter

```
Object.Body
```

that should have the file content.. But I can't seem to find a way to access it.

the Body is of type `io.ReadCloser`

Comment: What do you want to do with the body?  For example, do you want to copy the body to a file, decode the body as JSON or some other format, get a slice of bytes, ????

Comment: @CeriseLimón a slice of bytes.. and JSON.. I want both the formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
import "io/ioutil"
```

Then

```
bodyInBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(object.Body)
```

If you are using go after 1.16 then `io.ReadAll` is preferred, import `"io"`

You mention reading JSON in the comments. To read JSON, make a struct that matches the structure of your JSON document (use an online converter like https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ with a sample) then add `import "encoding/json"` and:

```
data := mystruct{}
err := json.Unmarshal(bodyInBytes, &data)
```